# Vertical and horizontal GridSplitter

Tags: wpf, gridsplitter

I have a grid and I am trying to put both vertical and horizontal GridSplitters.  It's my main grid and I would like it to be as fluid as possible.

On my second definition I get "Missing Grid.Column setter for non-first child"

I've found loads of documentation on implementing one or the other.  I have found nothing suggesting that I can do both.  But, our industry is made of people wanting to push functionality.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></GridSplitter>
    <GridSplitter  Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></GridSplitter>
```

Comment: Your `XAML` is missing from the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF vertical gridsplitter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305207/wpf-vertical-gridsplitter-not-working)

Answer (score 11):

You need to set Grid.Column for grid splitters and also you need

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  -> for horizontal splitter
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  -> for Vertical splitter
```

so your code looks like --

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" Grid.RowSpan ="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></GridSplitter>
<GridSplitter  Grid.Row="1" Height="5" Grid.ColumnSpan ="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></GridSplitter>
```

Comment: This only works because ResizeDirection=”Auto” will most likely choose by Alignment. But this is not how you really set the ResizeDirection.

Answer (score 3):

`ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"` needs to be added to allow proper adjustment of both columns and rows. See below for my sample.

```
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" Grid.RowSpan ="3" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext">
    </GridSplitter>
    <GridSplitter  Grid.Row="1" Height="5" Grid.ColumnSpan ="3" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext">            
    </GridSplitter>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="1,1" FontSize="30"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="3,1" FontSize="30"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="1,3" FontSize="30"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="3,3" FontSize="30"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: In the title you misspelled ResizeHehavior where it must be ResizeBehavior - Suggested edit queue is full

Comment: Spelling error fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the direction as follows:

```
<GridSplitter ResizeDirection=”Rows”/>
```

or

```
<GridSplitter ResizeDirection=”Columns”/>
```

However, when you set Alignment to either Horizontal or Vertical, the default ResizeDirection=”Auto” will most likely choose a fitting resize direction.

Comment: this doesnt really work. I want a vertical splitter and I set it to `Columns` it resizes the column the splitter sits in but the column on the left becomes resized in opposite direction. if you are so sure about your answer perhaps a more complete example would help

Comment: This is totally the expected behavior of the GridSplitter: Moving the split between two grid columns - make one smaller while the other becomes bigger. I don't understand your critique.